# How to Create a Magento Customer Record from a Shopify Sale

Tags: magento-1.9, api

I'm looking at the most efficient way to take shopify order information and send it to magento to create a customer record.

Obviously the API is the preferred method but I'm such a novice, rather than researching all the methodologies I'd rather someone just point me in the right direction & I'll get to work!

Thanks so much!

Comment: This isn't available yet, but sounds perfect http://marketlark.com

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to use [this](http://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/shopping-cart-migration-options/1044-shopify-to-magento-migration). There is not much to say about the way to import/export since this is a proprietary software. I have only heard good opinions about the platform, but I never it used myself.